# R - Title not removed with plot.title = element.blank() using plotly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I work with `ggplot2` and `plotly`. I must allow the user to choose the display of the title for a plot (displayed or not).

Therefore, I use the theme feature of `ggplot2` and more precisely `plot.title = element.blank()`. It works with `ggplot2` but the title is still there when I convert the plot in a plotly graph.

Any solution to fix the problem (other than remove the `labs()` function) ? Maybe a workaround with `plotly_build()`?

Here is a simplified example.

```
# Libraries and function
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

CountPlotFunction <- function(MyData)
{
  MyPlot <- ggplot(data = MyData, aes(x = MyData)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count", aes(fill = MyData)) +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
    labs(title = "A title for my plot") +
    ThemeByUser
  return(MyPlot)
}

# Data
CountryGroup <- c("Russia","Canada","Australia","Australia","Russia","Australia","Canada","Germany","Australia","Canada","Canada")
df <- data.frame(CountryGroup)

# Analysis
ThemeByUser <- theme(plot.title = element_blank()) # or NULL if we want the title...

ThePlot <- CountPlotFunction(MyData = df)

print(ThePlot) # OK with ggplot2
ggplotly(ThePlot) # NOK with plotly
```

Comment: `element_text(color="#00000000")` (0 alpha on color of title). You can make it be `element_text(color="#ffffff00")` if that seems more fitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotly_build()` will certainly work here:

```
ThemeByUser <- theme(plot.title = element_blank()) # or NULL if we want the title...

ThePlot <- CountPlotFunction(MyData = df)

pb <- plotly_build(ThePlot)

if(is.null(ThemeByUser)) {
  pb$x$layout$title <- NULL
}

pb
```